# Mysql select distinct values and last row

Tags: php, mysql

Very simple.

```
msg_id    msisdn           message 
----------------------------------   
1000      661000           text1   
1001      661002           text2   
1002      661004           text3   
1003      661002           text4   
1004      661002           text5     
1005      661002           text6
```

I need to get distinct msisdn values ordered from newest to oldest and all values in that last row. Please understand that there are more coluns in the real query so I need to get the distinct msisdn's - but also ALL DATA from last row with that msisdn.

```
msisdn     msg_id    message   
----------------------------- 
661002     1005      text6   
661004     1002      text3   
661000     1000      text1
```

Thanks!

Just to be clear. I started with:

select distinct(msisdn), max(msg_id) from table group by msisdn

However pulling all info about max(msg_id) is the problem... I need that whole row in the query, not just msg_id...

Hope it's all clearer now.

Comment: "and all values in that last row" - What do you mean by this?

Comment: This is something of a frequently asked question. The topic even has its own page in the manual. The contributors below might like to read it.

Comment: Strawberry, looks like it, however I haven't seen its answered right so far :-)

Comment: Szabolcs, tried everything on this page, still no good

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: Matt, well you could see from example. The only difference is that there are 20 more columns beside 'message' that I didnt want to include. The thing is that we need all values of the last row for that distinct value... (*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a derived table containing the max `msg_id` per `msisdn`, then join to this table to get the rest of the columns:

```
select t1.*
from mytable as t1
inner join (
   select msisdn, max(msg_id) as last_id
   from mytable
   group by msisdn
) as t2 on t1.msisdn = t2.msisdn and t1.msg_id = t2.last_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select msisdn,msg_id,max(message)
from table1
group by msg_id,msisdn
order by msg_id desc
```

Comment: will it give _ALL DATA from last row with that msisdn_ as mentioned

Comment: Hi Jordan, as I said, I need all columns (in real there are many more columns, not just message column), so I guess we will need * in this query somewhere

Comment: can you please post your complete table structure here?